# SpringData/Hibernate: Sorting by enum by character rather than index

Tags: java

I have a scenario to apply sorting based on enum column based on characters rather than index of the enums in the database and using querydsl for filtering the data to get pagination data.

Table in database :-

```
    CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    `task_status` enum('open','expired','approved','rejected') DEFAULT NULL
   );
```

> select * from test order by task_status asc;

```
id  taskStatus
3   open
4   expired
2   approved
1   rejected
```

The result above sorted based on index number of enum not text

But the query

> ```
> select * from test order by  CAST(task_status AS CHAR) asc; sorts based on text
> ```

```
id  taskStatus
2   approved
4   expired
3   open
1   rejected
```

I need the same to be applied through spring data jpa and my I am using

```
It can have multiple filter its just a dummy code
@GetMapping("/get")
    public Page<Test> getTest()  {
        QTest test = QTest.test;
        List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();
        ids.add(1);
        ids.add(2);
        ids.add(3);
        ids.add(4);
        BooleanExpression booleanExp = test.id.in(ids);
        Sort sort = new Sort(Direction.ASC, "taskStatus");
        return testRepo.findAll(booleanExp, PageRequest.of(0, 100, sort));
    }
```

returns the data sorted based on index of enum rather than text

```
{
 "content": [
     {
         "id": 3,
         "taskStatus": "OPEN"
     },
     {
         "id": 4,
         "taskStatus": "EXPIRED"
     },
     {
         "id": 2,
         "taskStatus": "APPROVED"
     },
     {
         "id": 1,
         "taskStatus": "REJECTED"
     }
 ],
 "pageable": {
     "sort": {
         "unsorted": false,
         "sorted": true,
         "empty": false
     },
     "offset": 0,
     "pageNumber": 0,
     "pageSize": 100,
     "paged": true,
     "unpaged": false
 },
 "last": true,
 "totalPages": 1,
 "totalElements": 4,
 "size": 100,
 "number": 0,
 "sort": {
     "unsorted": false,
     "sorted": true,
     "empty": false
 },
 "numberOfElements": 4,
 "first": true,
 "empty": false
}
```

Classes are

```
public enum TaskStatus {

  OPEN("open", "Open"), APPROVED("approved", "Approved"), REJECTED("rejected", "Rejected"), EXPIRED("expired",
      "Expired");
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class Test implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8697601034719624001L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TaskStatus taskStatus;
}
```

Pls help me on this.

Comment: Please logout the sql- statements and share it

Answer (score 1):

You can use @Query to declare your query

```
@Query("query select * from test order by CAST(task_status AS CHAR) asc")
public List<Test> getTest()
```

reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JPA repository you can just add this method to your repository interface:
`List<Test> findAllByOrderByTaskStatusAsc();`